# Indexing into CHOLMOD dense vector array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, suitesparse

I have a cholmod_dense data structure:

`cholmod_dense* ex = cholmod_l_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, B, &com);`

and I want to extract the values and copy them to another variable. This means I need to index into the double array and copy values over.

```
for (int k=0; k<ncols; k++) T_x[k]=((double*)ex->x)[k];
```

which the compiler is ok with but I get a segmenation fault. Or I think I should be able to do:

```
double* e_x =(double*)ex->x;
for (int k=0; k<ncols; k++) T_x[k]=*e_x[k];
```

But the compiler really dislikes this:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
for (int k=0; k<ncols; k++) T_x[k]= *e_x[k];
```

According to CHOLMOD userguide:

> 4. cholmod dense: A dense matrix, either real, complex or zomplex, in column-major order. This differs from the row-major convention used in C. A dense matrix X contains
>      • X->x, a double array of size X->nzmax or twice that for the complex case. • X->z, a double array of size X->nzmax if X is zomplex.

So I should be able to simply grab ex->x and index into it as a double array, but I cannot do so without getting a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me out?

The CHOLMOD library is written in C and the code that is linking to CHOLMOD library (the code snippet shown above) is c++.

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++, as they are two separate languages?  For example, C++ has `std::vector` and `std::array`, in which you could have a vector array.  The C language only has fixed sized arrays.  Also, the C++ language has `static_cast<>`.

Comment: Please edit your post with the "dislike" text from the compiler.

Comment: What is `ncols`?

Comment: `*e_x[k]` you are trying to dereference a `double`.  Did you mean `T_x[k] *= e_x[k]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks likes I made a couple mistakes.

First of all, I was running into a segmentation fault because I was using `cholmod_l_zeros();` which assumes `long integers`. Instead, I should be using `cholmod_zeros();` since I am using `doubles`.

After fixing this I ran into the error `CHOLMOD error: invalid xtype` right after my `cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, B, &com);` statement. This was because my `cholmod_factor* L` was defined out of scope. After fixing both of these issues, the code successfully copies values from `cholmod_dense ex->x double array` over to my `T_x double vector`:

```
cholmod_dense* ex = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, B, &com);
double* e_x = (double*)ex->x;
for (int k=0; k<ncols; k++) T_x[k] = e_x[k];
```

I also was unaware that the `[]` operator automatically dereferences pointers. Good to know!